# Reply-To Amazon SES field is ignored by auto responders

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I'm sending notification emails to users of my web app via Amazon SES. The notification email is regarding an action taken by another user, so I set the Reply-To field to that other user's email address so that users can hit reply and reply to that member.

However, if someone has set up Auto-Reply on their email, the Reply-To field is ignored and it bounces back to my noreply@domain.com email address. I can't spoof the "From" email to be that user's email, as far as I can tell, because Amazon SES does not allow you to do this.

Is there a solution to this? It's important for a member to receive the other member's Auto-Reply so that they know that they are out of office.

Thanks.

Comment: How many users on average have that strange auto-reply set?

Comment: it's a standard "away from office" or "vacation" auto-reply on their emails, and it does happen often but requires us to manually forward to the correct member.

Comment: Amazon considers this recipient a bounce like if it was a suppression list recipient. In order to know who is ooo (out of office) you should set up an sns notification to inform you about which recipients bounce with this particular status. Then you can play with them in your code in order to re-build the notification to the right recipient. In any case, you don't want to send any email 'FROM' a recipient which is out of office as anyone replying to him, will again get an ooof email.

Answer (score -1):

Similar thread here, with no solution other then using separate email for sending
[see here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/topic/8485/reply-to-address-ignored-by-autoresponders/)

Comment: The link in your answer is dead. Also, it's bad practice to simply link to other websites in a SO answer